# Anime about a boy getting chased through a school?

Tags: magical-warfare

This is what I do remember about it:

- I saw it either in 2013/2014 on either Anime Network or Funimation Channel.

  - It was a free preview episode.
- I remember the main character was a guy, and he was fighting/running his way through a corridor that I think was part of a school/academy.

  - The building was brick or stone I think.
- I'm not sure, but he may have been pulled to the school from another world/dimension.
- The guy was being chased by different groups of people, and they were all trying to fight him, but I can't remember if they had magic or just weapons.
- I'm pretty sure most of the characters were male.
- I remember there was a tall, strong man type guy in one group.
- The main character runs into a pretty boy type in an outside garden area.
- For some reason, all of the characters had to fight each other or had to fight the main character.
- The people chasing the main character were in groups of 3 or 4.

I don't remember much about the plot, only what I saw.  Any help would be appreciated. ^-^

Answer (score 4):

I think the anime you are looking for is [Magical Warfare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magical_Warfare), the events you described are from the first episode.

The strong man is Takao Oigami

[image]

The pretty boy should be Kazumi Ida

[image]

> Takeshi Nanase is an ordinary high school boy who has a somewhat dark past. However, one day, he comes across a girl named Mui Aiba, in a uniform he has never seen before, collapsed on the school campus. This encounter changes Takeshi's destiny completely. Mui tells Takeshi that she is a magician, and she apologizes, for she turned Takeshi into a magician, too. What Takeshi once knew as one world is actually two — the world where magicians live and the world where humans live.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the pretty boy was blond, but I could be mistaken as the red head looks familiar.  I'll check this out and see if this is it.  Thank you!

Comment: @foxmom85 I have altered the answer to show the other pretty boy.